# System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt version mismatch on Nuget packaging

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nuget, teamcity, jwt, octopus-deploy

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or
>   one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition
>   does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80131040)

I have somehow returned to DLL hell.

I have an asp.net MVC app that I want to deploy via our CI:

1. TeamCity (`2017.1.3`) with the Octopusplugin ([TeamCity Plugin](https://octopus.com/downloads))
2. Octopus deploying to azure website app

I've gotten this same pipeline to work for other web apps, but for this one MVC app that utilizes `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt`, version `4.0.4.403061554`.

I run the app locally, and the FileAssembly version referenced is `4.0.4.403061554` as expected. However, when team city builds the nuget package, and I download and extract it, the `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt` file assembly version is set to `5.1.4.216` which is not what I am expecting.

I've drilled through all of my packages deplendencies, none are referencing this version of the dll.

I have searched through all of my files for any refernece of 5.1.4, nothing exists.

I have also checked the feature to `Disable looking up packages from local machine cache` when refreshing packages in TeamCity.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a straight answer here, however a couple thoughts which could hopefully help in the right direction.

Maybe there is a lower level dependency to this package in any other project or nuget package, which gets built together and as a result the latest version gets into build directory? Just noted that the 5.1.4 is the latest version of `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt`.

I presume you employ `BindingRedirect` to version 4. Have there been braking changes? Could you not switch to using the latest version?

Have you looked in the build folder of the [build server](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Build+Checkout+Directory)? Maybe you could narrow down the project/folder with the version 5.1.4?